# Laravel 5.3 Return ? on Where Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I've sucessfully created many functions using `where` query on Laravel 5.3, but this time something weird is happening.

```
public function show($id){
    $artikel = Artikel::select('artikel.*','kategori.kategori_id','kategori.kategori_nama','users.name','users.user_photo','users.biodata')
            ->join('kategori','artikel.kategori_id','=','kategori.kategori_id')
            ->join('users','user_id','=','id')
            ->orderBy('view','desc')
            ->find($id);
    $kategori = Kategori::all();
    $sub = Artikel::select('kategori_id')->where('artikel_id',$id)->toSql();
    dd($sub);
    $related = Artikel::where('kategori_id','=',$sub)
                ->get();
    dd($related);
    if($artikel == null ){
        $artikel = new Artikel; 
        $artikel->pesan=0;

        foreach ($artikel as $post) {
            $this->putInCache( $post->slug, $post, 'artikel' );
        }
        return view('artikel.show')->with('artikel',$artikel)->with('kategori',$kategori);
    }

    $artikel->view+=1;
    $artikel->save();

    return view('artikel.show')->with('artikel',$artikel)->with('kategori',$kategori)->with('related',$related);
}
```

The method outputs an error on line 8. The `dd()` on line 9 returned

```
"select `kategori_id` from `artikel` where `artikel_id` = ?"
```

I've tried to change the query to

```
$sub = Artikel::select('kategori_id')->where('artikel_id','=',1)->toSql();
```

And much more, but still got an error. That line returned `?` on where clause. Please help me.

Thank you!

**UPADTE 1**

Now the code is like this :

```
$related = Artikel::where('kategori_id','=','select kategori_id from artikel where artikel_id = 1')
                ->get();
```

and the result is returned empty collection.

> Collection {#272 ▼
>     #items: []
>   }

Comment: What is the exact error/exception you're getting?

Comment: @Danu Akbar **toSql()** will not return full query because of **bind parameter**. use `->get()` instead of `->toSql()` . This will show you the output.

Comment: @phaberest that the exactly

Comment: @Manish now i edited the code like this : `$related = Artikel::where('kategori_id','=','select kategori_id from artikel where artikel_id = 1')
                    ->get();` and the return is Collection {#272 ▼
  #items: []
}

Comment: @Danu Akbar Use whereRaw instead of where.here are the examples you can use.
[https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries]
[https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/how-do-you-parameterize-whereraw-in-the-query-builder]

Answer (score 1):

It's not an error, `?` [is normal](https://scotch.io/tutorials/debugging-queries-in-laravel). `toSql()` method shows `?` sign instead of values in a query.

> This method is great for quickly seeing the SQL. However, it doesn’t
>   include the query bindings, only a ? for where they are to be
>   inserted. Depending on the complexity of the bindings, this may be
>   enough information for you to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the working. There's the code :

```
$sub = DB::raw('(select kategori_id from artikel where artikel_id =1)');
    $related = DB::table('artikel')->select('*')->where('kategori_id','=',($sub))->get();
    dd($related);
```